# How to change a nuget packet assembly version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-assembly, stackexchange.redis

In `Visual Studio` with my **Asp.net core project**, I have used some **nuget packets** (like `StackExchange.Redis`, `Serilog` etc..).  I decided to use Visual studio 2019. Everything was going well, but one day I noticed some projects couldn't update their referenced projects in solution. Because they are (.net standard libraries) taking output codes to obj folder instead bin folder. 
I decided to return Visual Studio 2017. Everything working great with VS2017, but this time it giving me a run time error such as could not found referenced assembly public key etc.. like below

I have removed old pockets from all projects in the solution by the package manager `nuget manager`. I have installed a new version by the nuget manager tool. But project always seemto be using the old version.

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'StackExchange.Redis, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46'. The system cannot find the file specified.

For example, if I install a nuget packet version 2.0.0.0 and I want to remove it all from project and I want to install a new version by an upgrade or downgrade. What should I do? How can I change it?

Update: I have uninstalled 2 packages from nuget and from windows, still project seen this assemblies!
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error CS0433  The type 'ConnectionMultiplexer' exists in both
>   'StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46' and 'StackExchange.Redis,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c219ff1ca8c2ce46'  Tursys.Pool.Storage.Api D:\projects\tursys\PoolStorage\src\Tursys.Pool.Storage.Api\Startup.cs   76  Active

Both of them not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, for anyone:

- VS-2019 corrected it's output folder as bin folder with a new bug-fix! but it was not related with the nuget package removement problem

**How to remove a package from a project:**
In Visual Studio i want to go to file with F12 key. And with the open target folder command i see the local folder of the removed package as

> C:\Users\HAMIT\AppData\Local\Temp\MetadataAsSource\821e7bd605414042826501fe0b5cdc21\32ae5450ea724e84b62f983bdb6bb879

I have deleted this temp files but by the rebuild process VS restored them again. This some bored me and i found a new manner. There is always a technic to removing a package from the VisualStudio with the **-force** argument like below in PM Console

```
Uninstall-Package -ProjectName "YourProjectName" -RemoveDependencies -Force
```

When you put this command it will asking you the PackageId will be removed. Write your package name and it is ok!

If you dont know your package name exactly then you can get a list according your project like below:

```
Get-Package -ProjectName "YourProjectName"
```

- But uninstalling to StackExchange.Redis.StrongName still is enigma!!!

UPDATE: I found a solution for this too! Change Aspnetcore framework 2.2 to 3.0 under Visual Studio 2019. Now seem to right dlls and Everything corrected.

Comment: Probably via Microsoft.AspNetCore.All? https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1134#issuecomment-487054788

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

- Install-Package "YourProjectName" -Version 6.2.0